# tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage" doesn't exist with Button wrapper class

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

A common problem with Tkinter is that in order to use images in Labels and Buttons, you need a reference to the PhotoImage object... somehow.

I have written a wrapper class around Button to add my own functionalities, because I want to use GIFs instead of images, and I want to be able to switch between gifs when I press the button (or use a `keyboard` hotkey). The first GIF runs fine and loops perfectly. When I switch to the second GIF, I get the error message, saying `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage48` ... `pyimage55" doesn't exist`. It looks like the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class AnimatedButton(Button)
  def __init__(self, master, size, img_paths):
    self.size = size
    self.seq_count = len(img_paths) # Number of gif files
    self.sequences = []

    for path in img_paths:
      gif, delay = loadGif(path)
      # Create a tuple of all frames in a gif, with the delay between frames. Store this tuple in self.sequences
      self.sequences.append(([ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame) for frame in gif], delay))

    self.delay = self.sequences[0][1]
    self.current_sequence = self.sequences[0][0]
    self.image = self.current_sequence[0]

    self.seq_id = 0 # Sequence counter
    self.frame_id = 0 # Frame counter
    Button.__init__(self, master, image=self.image, width=size, height=size)
    self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

  def play(self):
    self.image = self.current_sequence[self.frame_id]
    self.config(image=self.image)
    # More stuff below to loop through the frames etc.
```

What is strange is that I don't have any of this with my other Button class, `MyButton`, also a wrapper class.

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, size, img_paths):
        self.image_count = len(img_paths)
        self.image_id = 0
        self.size = size

        self.images = []
        for path in img_paths:
            try:
                im = Image.open(path)
            except:
                print("Could not open file {}".format(path))
            photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im, image_mode)
            self.images.append(photo_image)
        self.image = self.images[0]

        Button.__init__(self, master, image=self.image, width=size,
                        height=size)
```

Most Google searches came up with the fact that you shouldn't use two tkinter.Tk() calls, but I am only using one (Yes, I made sure).

Any ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Why? Because we run the code in order to analyze it and if we have to write own code that runs it might not be the same code you are running.

Comment: You create a `list` of `list`: `.append(([ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame) for ...`, should be `list` only.

Comment: @stovfl that is by design. I store multiple sequences of multiple frames, i.e. list of lists.

Comment: ***that is by design***: OK, but then you can't access **one** image with: `self.current_sequence[0]` because this returns a `list` of images.

Comment: @figbeam That is practically impossible. The entire program is one big pipeline. Might not be good practise, but I am new, which is why I am here.

Comment: @Jeroen Ritmeester: Well, you don't have to post your whole program, just an example that illustrates how your button doesn't work. A **minimal** example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by stovfl in the comments above, I was missing `[0]` in `play()`:

Correct code should be:

```
def play(self):
    self.image = self.current_sequence[self.frame_id][0]
    self.config(image=self.image)
    # More stuff below to loop through the frames etc.
```